# Import using absolute path using Webpack and Electron

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, electron

I am trying to import a file with an absolute path into my main electron thread.

Import code in the main electron thread:

```
import * as Test2 from 'app/main/tray.js';
```

I have added the resolve.root to the webpack.config:

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader',
    }],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]/index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve('./')
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    packageMains: ['webpack', 'browser', 'web', 'browserify', ['jam', 'main'], 'main'],
  },
  plugins: [

  ],
  externals: [
    // put your node 3rd party libraries which can't be built with webpack here
    // (mysql, mongodb, and so on..)
  ],
};
```

No errors are thrown when I run the webpack server (webpack finds the files just fine) but an error is thrown when I run electron.

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'app/main/tray.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Git\stemn-electron-2\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:22:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at loader (C:\Git\stemn-electron-2\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Git\stemn-electron-2\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Git\stemn-electron-2\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:288:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Git\stemn-electron-2\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:330:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start-hot"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! STEMN@0.0.1 start-hot: `cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill ./app/main/index`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the STEMN@0.0.1 start-hot script 'cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill ./app/main/index'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the STEMN package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill ./app/main/index
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs STEMN
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls STEMN
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Git\stemn-electron-2\npm-debug.log
```

It looks like electron is changing the webpack import behavior? These files are imported properly in the renderer windows, just not the main thread...

Comment: Did you try import module with relative path `'./app/main/tray.js'`?

Comment: Yes, importing using relative works, it is only absolute import that is not working.

Comment: `app/main/tray.js` doesn't look like an absolute path to me

Comment: He specified the root path in the webpack config. When webpack runs, it takes that path and adds it to `app/main/tray.js`. At least it should work like that. The problem is, it is not.

Comment: Indeed, `root: [path.resolve('./')]` makes the path absolute.

I should make this point clear: as far as webpack is concerned, this is working fine (there are no errors when webpack runs). The errors only occur inside the electron app. The error message makes me think it is something to do with how `electron-prebuilt` deals with imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the I was using webpack to build the electron renderers but not using webpack to build the electron main-thread.

I added a new webpack.config specifically for the main thread - now I can use webpack.root (but all the code must compile now which is a bit of a shame...)

Comment: Can you share how you start the main process via webpack as well? Everywhere I see the `electron` CLI being used for main and webpack only for the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
root: [
     path.resolve(__dirname)
]
```